# SqlServer clustered index storage ( >1 columns )?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, clustered-index

lets say i have a table like this :

```
a | b | c | d 
______________
1 | 2 | 4 | 5
6 | 2 | 5 | 5
3 | 5 | 2 | 5
```

`[a]` column has  clustered index

so the physical order which its stored is :

```
a | b | c | d 
______________
1 | 2 | 4 | 5
3 | 5 | 2 | 5
6 | 2 | 5 | 5
```

now lets enhance the `[a]` index to be `[a,c]` ( still as clustered).

now , I can't udnerstand how it can be stored since `[a]` column  is already sorted and `[c]` column cant be sorted ( because sorting of `[a]` hurts the sorting of `[c]`)

so how does sqlServer will store it ?

2'nd question : do I need to open another index for `[c]` ?

Comment: This clusted index (a or a&c) is unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite indexes produce [lexicographical order](http://Lexicographical%20order): the records are additionally ordered on `c` when values of `a` are considered "equal".

```
a c
1 2
2 3 -- Within this block, records are sorted on [c]
2 5 --
2 7 --
3 7
4 1
5 6 -- Within this block, records are sorted on [c]
5 8 --
```

This is how dictionaries sort.

You need an additional index on `c` if you want to speed up queries not involving `a`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   c = @some_value
```

Comment: so [c] will be part of [a,c] index for those queries that uses [a],[c] ............ and [c] will have ANOTHER index for queriyes that uses [c] only ?

Comment: `c` will be a part of an index on `(a, c)` regardless of the queries. Queries which filter on `a` AND `c` (or on `a` only) will use the index on `(a, c)`; queries which filter on `c` only will use the index on `c` only.

Comment: sorry for irrelevent question , bu ti really want to learn about **decisions** for creating indexes. do you have a helpful link ? all links ive found is about indexing in general and not about decisions....

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing something obvious.  Consider what you would expect from the query

```
select * from myTable
order by [a], [c]
```

Your clustered index on columns [a,c] will give a physical layout with the same order.